# Sporadic Signin using Traefik with Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: windows-authentication, traefik

I'm having an issue getting Traefik to proxy applications that are secured using Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA). When the content being served is simply an IIS virtual directory secured with IWA there is no problem. However, when it is a .NET Core application or MVC application or even just a simple Default.aspx page and IWA is enabled I continually get prompted for my credentials (never being accepted). See below for my configuration:

```
Traefik Configuration:

  # ns-ws
  [frontends.ns_ws]
  passHostHeader=true
  entrypoints=["http","https"]
  backend = "ns_ws"
    [frontends.ns_ws.routes.match_all]
    rule = "Host:ns-ws.example.com"

  [backends.ns_ws]
    # ns-ws
    [backends.ns_ws.loadbalancer.stickiness]
    [backends.ns_ws.servers.server1]
    url = "http://x.x.x.x:80"
```

I've played with removing pass host headers and stickiness, but no luck.

Seems like the original request makes it through because I do not get an unauthenticated error message from IIS for the page, but most subsequent requests to the server will return a 401 (seems sporadic).

[Example Image](https://photos.app.goo.gl/9xADw2HDUCrcLnJB8):
[image: Example]

I've tried changing the "authPersistNonNTLM" option in IIS, as described here: https://boyan.io/kerberos-load-balancers/ (with no luck)

Comment: To my knowledge IWA uses either Kerberos or NTLM for authentication. If NTLM is used one needs to be aware that this protocol does not work through proxies (see for instance in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936501/reverse-proxying-an-ntlm-protected-website) or in this old [Microsoft knowledge base article](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/198116)).

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a very stale issue but in case this helps others.

I can confirm that Windows Integrated authentication works successfully with Traefik 2.x using a TCP as opposed to HTTP router with successful logins proven on Windows/Mac using Safari/Chrome/IE.

Note that when testing it is important to ensure you have cleared cookie caches or you can get unpredictable results due to prior login attempts on non-working configurations you may have attempted.  Indeed I experienced something similar to your described behavior with repeated unexplained login prompts until I reset my browser.

In our configuration we have a mixed-OS docker Swarm (Linux/Windows) with Traefik operating on Linux and sending requests straight to back-end Windows-containers running on Windows swarm nodes.

If you have configured your Windows app and containers correctly I can confirm that from:

- A domain-joined machine you will get straight through login to Windows back-end containers using the domain-joined machine's Kerberos credentials
- A non-domain-joined machine connection will downgrade to Windows NTLM authentication and prompt for Windows authentication credentials.

From a Traefik configuration perspective our docker containers have labels like this:

```
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.dotnet-tcpexample.entrypoints=websecure"
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.dotnet-tcpexample.tls=true"
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.dotnet-tcpexample.tls.options=default"
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.dotnet-tcpexample.rule=HostSNI(`windows.foo.bar`)"
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.dotnet-tcpexample.tls.passthrough=true"
    - "traefik.tcp.routers.dotnet-tcpexample.service=dotnet-tcpexample"
    - "traefik.tcp.services.dotnet-tcpexample.loadbalancer.server.port=443"
```

Note that configuring containers for Windows integrated authentication in itself is non-trivial but documented [here](https://success.docker.com/article/modernizing-traditional-dot-net-applications).